# Why this pointer is cast to char and not to any other?

Tags: c

While implementing my own sizeof operator, I came across one example which is stated below.

```
#define my_sizeof(type) (char *)(&type+1)-(char*)(&type)
int main()
{
    double x;
    printf("%d", my_sizeof(x));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure about why they used (char *) in the #define and not any other type cast. I need to know exact significance of the stated syntax. Can someone help me in understanding this one..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to understand what is stated in #define.. %lu is unsigned long.. but thn why it is casted to (char *)..? What is significance..??

Comment: Well, first off, the argument is poorly named. it should be `var` since that it the only thing you can pass into this macro. Secondly, it is using typed-pointer arithmetic to advance a constant memory address (&type) one object past its current address (which is undefined behavior for anything but arrays, by the way). It then casts the result address to char pointer (which this code assumes is a single octet) and subtracts a char-pointer cast of the original address. in the end this is computing the "size" of the object in memory in sizeof(char) elements, using undefined behavior to do it.

Comment: And back to the hint. Ask yourself, what is the size of a `char` ? Thus the statement, perhaps `printf("%lu\n", sizeof(char));` may offer some insight as to why this uses `char*` for casting, but you won't understand that until you also understand how typed-pointer arithmetic works (which is the important part of the `+1` in your macro). If you don't understand that, I'll be more than happy to explain it. It is pretty important to how pointers work in C.

Comment: printf("%lu\n", sizeof(char)); This give me output as "1".. That i know very well. But I am still much confused about usage of (char).. What is the significance.. Just a simple question. Do you know what exactly is happening in the compiler side..??

Comment: Char is the smallest addressable type. Similar effect can be achieved by casting the address of `a[1]` to intptr_t (or any integer large enough to represent all addresses in the system).

Comment: It is precisely because it is (usually) 1 that it is used. The same cannot be said for `double`, `int`, etc. See claptraps answer below. it is a pretty solid example of why they use this.

Comment: @HirenPandya : You need to learn etiquette man.

Comment: @WhozCraig: "*which is undefined behavior for anything but arrays*" -- A single object behaves like an array with one element, as far as pointer arithmetic is concerned. See 6.5.6 (7) in the standard.

Comment: @Secure you are right on that, I often forget that this is one area where C and C++ (native tongue) may differ. Edit: sure enough its right there, "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type." I completely bow to the standard. Thank you for the correction, sir. I just checked C++11 5.7.4 and its there too. I would have *sworn* it was UB for single elements in C++, though I'm not surprised it isn't in C. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to understand it you need to know that when you write

```
double d[2];
double *p = d;
p = p + 1;      p is now pointing to the next double i.e. &d[1]
```

in memory `p` has moved `sizeof(double)` bytes forward

if you treat p as a character pointer you can get the number of bytes that the offset has changed instead:

```
double d[2];
double *p = d;
char* start = (char*)p; 
p = p + 1;
char* end = (char*)p;
```

now `end-start` gives the offset in bytes (characters) IOW `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: +1 Solid example of typed-pointer arithmetic. It is more precisely, indeed `sizeof(double)` *as measured in char-size*, which is almost always 1 octet. Also note that (p - d) will yield `1` in the first example (the same arithmetic that advanced p will also return that advancement, which is why the second example uses casts to `char*` to force a typed-pointer to be a type that is a single octet wide. Good example.

Comment: Thnx to all.. this helped me a lot.. but what is the significance of this syntax thn.. -> #define MYSIZEOF(X) ((X*)0 +1).. It does the same thing ??

Comment: @HirenPandya very similar, but that takes a different road into Ub land. It uses the "value" of the address offset from 0 (assumed to be NULL) advanced by 1 type-of-X-bytes-wide distance. The resulting "pointer" would then be the size of the type (in theory). Ex: ((int *)0+1) If `int` is 4 bytes wide, this results of the expression being a pointer with the "address" of 0x00000004. However, this is totally undefined behavior, and would likely fall flat on its face in a system that uses a segment:offset pointer architecture. in the end, just use the built-in `sizeof()`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `sizeof char` is (by definition) 1. They cast to `char *` to be able to subtract pointers to get the size of the object pointed at.

This will mostly work, but AFAIU willy-nilly "pointing to the next object" if it isn't in an array is not always guaranteed to work right. Besides, the size of an object with the requited padding in an array isn't necessarilily the size of the object.

Bletcherous. Just use `sizeof`.
`

Comment: As you have stated... "but AFAIU willy-nilly "pointing to the next object" if it isn't in an array is not always guaranteed to work right.".. Can you please provide me some example for the same ?